# What is the meaning of 1.5 ton in air conditioner specifications?

Tags: power, power-consumption

I'm interested in calculating amount of power consumed in an hour. Does 1.5 ton means 1500kWh?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about air conditioning.

Comment: Nope, I'm interested in meaning of the unit ton. And amount of power consumed.

Comment: A ton is 1,000kg. Maybe it's being used to define a quantity of air?

Comment: off topic? I asked a question about a unit of power. Is there a more appropriate site for power units?

Comment: Maybe physics.SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ["ton" in air conditioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_conditioning#Energy) circles is a reference to the heat capacity of a ton of melting water ice, over the period of one day. It is defined as 12000 BTU/hr, or 3517 watts.

Note that this is a measurement of the heat transferred away from the cold side of the system. The actual power consumed to accomplish this depends on the overall efficiency of the system. The amount of heat coming out of the hot side will be the sum of the two values.